# Создание фильтра просмотра (odoo)

Tags: odoo

Есть [odoo](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjACahUKEwiP3Ynks-THAhWCD3IKHSmVBj4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fodoo%2Fodoo&usg=AFQjCNEd33_QMTgqi4CdhboHVZzh3eUSBQ&sig2=jYX_z9Pdi__6ibDkIrRjcw) с самописным модулем табеля учёта рабочего времени. Возникла необходимость накидать фильтров отображения в xml-файле во views, но если первый (по умолчанию) прошёл на ура, то последующие уже по какой-то причине не отображаются.

```
<!-- tabel search view 1 -->
    <record id="view_tabel_search1" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">tabel.tabel.search1</field>
            <field name="model">tabel.tabel</field>
            <field name="type">search</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Checker">
                <filter
                string="Прошлый и последующие месяцы"
                name="filter1"
                domain="[('write_date', '>=' ,(context_today()-relativedelta(months=2)+relativedelta(days=20)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y') )]"
                help = "Чтобы посмотреть табели за прошлые месяцы, нажмите ВСЕ"/>
                <field name="time_start_t" select="True"/>
                <field name="id_ank" select="True"/>
            </search>
            </field>
    </record>

<!--tabel search view 2 -->
    <record id="view_tabel_search2" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">tabel.tabel.search2</field>
            <field name="model">tabel.tabel</field>
            <field name="type">search</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Checker">
                <filter
                string="Текущий и последующие месяцы"
                name="filter3"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '>=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))]"
                help = "Чтобы посмотреть табели за прошлые месяцы, нажмите ВСЕ"/>
                <field name="time_start_t" select="True"/>
                <field name="id_ank" select="True"/>
            </search>
            </field>
    </record>
```

Первый отображается, второй — нет. Вся разница между ними в том, что первый — фильтр по умолчанию, что отмечается отдельно в actions.

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="tabel_list_draft_action">
        <field name="name">На подпись табельщика</field>
        <field name="res_model">tabel.tabel</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('state','=', 'draft')]</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form,graph</field>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_tabel_search2"/>
        <field name="context">{'search_default_filter1':1,'state':'draft'}</field>
</record>
```

Может быть, фильтры не по умолчанию также нужно каким-то образом описывать в actions, хоть в мануалах такого я не видел. В общем, буду благодарен за любой совет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё оказалось куда проще, как подсказали в англоязычном СО, внутри search view можно описывать несколько фильтров.
Рабочий пример ниже:

```
<!-- tabel search view 1 -->
    <record id="view_tabel_search1" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">tabel.tabel.search1</field>
            <field name="model">tabel.tabel</field>
            <field name="type">search</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Checker">
                <filter
                string="Прошлый и последующие месяцы"
                name="filter1"
                domain="[('write_date', '>=' ,(context_today()-relativedelta(months=2)+relativedelta(days=20)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y') )]"
                help = "Чтобы посмотреть табели за прошлые месяцы нажмите ВСЕ"/>
                <filter
                string="Текущий и последующие месяцы"
                name="filter2"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '>=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))]"
                help = "Чтобы посмотреть табели за прошлые месяцы нажмите ВСЕ"/>
                <field name="time_start_t" select="True"/>
                <field name="id_ank" select="True"/>
            </search>
            </field>
    </record>
```

Ну и конечно же нужно указать его как дефолтный в *actions*:

```
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="tabel_list_draft_action">
        <field name="name">На подпись табельщика</field>
        <field name="res_model">tabel.tabel</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('state','=', 'draft')]</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form,graph</field>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_tabel_search2"/>
        <field name="context">{'search_default_filter1':1,'state':'draft'}</field>
    </record>
```